# Continuously running and restarting python scripts on a remote server

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have 3-4 python scripts which I want to run continuously on a remote server(which i am accessing through ssh login).The script might crash due to exceptions(handling all the exceptions is not practical now), and in such cases i want to immediately restart the  script.

What i have done till now.
I have written a .conf file in /etc/init

> chdir /home/user/Desktop/myFolder
>   exec python myFile.py
>   respawn

This seemed to work fine for about 4 hours and then it stopped working and i could not start the .conf file.

Suggest changes to this or i am also open to a new approach

Comment: What do you mean that "handling all the exceptions is not practical now"?

Comment: have you considered checking for the process on the unix/linux box, and then if that's not present, restarting the script?

Comment: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html

Comment: Try amazon AWS (EC2, EMR). I know this is like Mount Everest. Hay, but if you can climb it, there's nothing that can stop you.

Comment: @Damon how would AWS help with this problem?

Comment: To amplify @Marcin, do something with the Exceptions so the program doesn't crash. You are trying to fix the wrong problem (program is dead) when you should be addressing the root cause (unhandled Exceptions are killing the program.)

Comment: @Joe the amazon EMR has inbuilt facility to create and manage jobs assigned to EC2 machines. If any python code is defined as job, then it would be a lot more easier to manage those with Amazon EMR. If a job fails (i.e. crashes), then it can be re-assigned to any other or same  worker. This is extremely easy if you are familiar with EMR.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it - run in infinite bash loop in screen. Also it's the worst way to do it:

```
screen -S sessionName bash -c 'while true; python myFile.py ; done'
```

You can also use http://supervisord.org/ or daemon by writing init.d script for it http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts

Answer (score 1):

If your script is running on an Ubuntu machine you have the very convenient Upstart, http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Upstart does a great job running services on boot and respawning a process that died.